# Wordpress Metabox with Radio Inputs generated by Javascript ( checked() wordpress function in Javascript alternative)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I was searching through this and other forums for answer, but I'm still facing this problem without any progress.

In code below, I have two Radio inputs. They are generating in post edit page of Wordpress CMS and their values are post_meta values. Everything works fine, but because it is jQuery, I cant use function [checked()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/checked), so after I click Publish, they are visible as unchecked. Is there a way, to solve this anyhow?

```html
function addRow(image_url){

    if(typeof(image_url)==='undefined') image_url = "";
    itemsCount+=1;

    var emptyRowTemplate = '<div id=row-'+itemsCount+'> <input style=\'width:70%\' id=img-'+itemsCount+' type=\'text\' name=\'miu_images['+itemsCount+']\' value=\''+image_url+'\' />'
    +'<input type=\'button\' href=\'#\' class=\'Image_button button\' id=\'Image_button-'+itemsCount+'\' value=\'Upload\'>'
    +'<input class="miu-remove button" type=\'button\' value=\'Remove\' id=\'remove-'+itemsCount+'\' /><br>'
    
    +'<label for="left-column'+itemsCount+'">Lewa kolumna</label><input name=\'float['+itemsCount+']\' type=\'radio\' value=\'left-column\' id=\'left-column'+itemsCount+'\' />'
    +'<label for="right-column'+itemsCount+'">Prawa kolumna</label><input name=\'float['+itemsCount+']\' type=\'radio\' value=\'right-column\' id=\'right-column'+itemsCount+'\' />'

    '</div>';
    jQuery('#miu_images').append(emptyRowTemplate);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to pass the existing values to your script at the point that the script is loaded.

When you are using wp_enqueue_script to enqueue your script, set the $in_footer parameter to true so the script loads in the footer.

Then, when you are setting up the meta box on the WordPress post edit page, use wp_localize_script to pass your script the meta values. For example:

```
// Get post meta values for float in array $float
$data = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= count($float); $i++) {
    $data['float' . $i] = $float[$i - 1];
}
wp_localize_script('some_handle', 'floatdata', $data);
```

where 'some_handle' is the handle you used in your wp_enqueue_script.

This will create a Javascript variable of the form:

```
<script>
var floatdata = {
    'float1': value of float1,
    'float2': value of float2,
    ...
};
</script>
```

Then, as your script creates rows, it can check the value of `floatdata.floatn` and set 'checked="checked"' accordingly.

So, for example,

```
function addRow(image_url){

    if(typeof(image_url)==='undefined') image_url = "";
    itemsCount+=1;
    var radiovalue = floatdata['float'+itemsCount];

    var emptyRowTemplate = '<div id=row-'+itemsCount+'> <input style=\'width:70%\' id=img-'+itemsCount+' type=\'text\' name=\'miu_images['+itemsCount+']\' value=\''+image_url+'\' />'
    +'<input type=\'button\' href=\'#\' class=\'Image_button button\' id=\'Image_button-'+itemsCount+'\' value=\'Upload\'>'
    +'<input class="miu-remove button" type=\'button\' value=\'Remove\' id=\'remove-'+itemsCount+'\' /><br>'

    +'<label for="left-column'+itemsCount+'">Lewa kolumna</label><input name=\'float['+itemsCount+']\' type=\'radio\' value=\'left-column\' id=\'left-column'+itemsCount+'\'' + (radiovalue == 'left-column' ? ' checked="checked"' : '') + ' />'
    +'<label for="right-column'+itemsCount+'">Prawa kolumna</label><input name=\'float['+itemsCount+']\' type=\'radio\' value=\'right-column\' id=\'right-column'+itemsCount+'\'' + (radiovalue == 'right-column' ? ' checked="checked"' : '') + ' />'

    '</div>';
    jQuery('#miu_images').append(emptyRowTemplate);
}
```

Comment: Thank for your answer ;)

I passed this variables to my script, but I have few questions. First, my array looks like:

/* <![CDATA[ */
var floatdata = {"float0":"right-column","float1":"left-column"};
/* ]]> */

Shouldn't it count float[n] from 1? Because my rows starting from 1.

Second question, should I add any condition to my inputs in *.js file? If yes, how would it look like?

Comment: I changed the answer to start at 1. It's not necessary, but avoids having to adjust the index when you are looking at the data. I also added some words about modifying the .js file. Let me know if that answers your question.

Comment: When its starting from 1, it's not getting the first value of $float array with meta values, but it's not a big problem, honestly, I have no idea how to compare this values and set right radio to be checked. Tell my if I'm thinking wrong: I should loop through each radio buttons group, compare values like: float0 = "left-column" so I'm looking for this value in first radio group and set checked to radio that have this value?

Comment: I dont have condition yet, but now, thanks to you I can understand how it would work, so thank you, you helped me a lot already ;) But how to make this "N counter" work?. To call values of the array I can use floatdata.float1, floatdata.float2..

Comment: In Javascript, you can treat an object like an array. So if itemsCount is your counter, you can reference values in floatdata by floatdata['float'+itemsCount]. Then, as you said, you would look at the value and decide which of the two radio buttons to add the 'checked' attribute to.

Comment: I have started to write condition like emptyRowTemplate = emptyRowTemplate.replace('%checked%', (jQuery("#multi_image_upload_meta_box input[type='radio']").val() == floatdata['side'+itemsCount] ? 'checked="checked"' : '')); but as far as I can see, I cant get value of radio input in this conditions because it's empty. Besides, I tried to console.log(floatdata[1]) and it returns error.

Comment: I edited the answer to show a different way of doing it, with some code. I might have made a typo, but it shows the general idea of doing it without a string replace, just inserting the checked at the right place in the HTML.

Comment: Its working! oh man, u're saving me (I hate deadlines). But now itemsCount are not in place, its counting from 1, so I'm missing first value of my floatdata array. Why this solution radiovalue = floatdata['float'+itemsCount - 1 ]; is not working?

Comment: I mentioned above (maybe you missed it) that I changed it so that it counted from 1 instead of 0. You can do it either way. You just need to subtract 1 or not depending on which approach you take.

Comment: I noticed your edit, changed my code, but with this change, last item of array floatdata is empty. I'm working on it, but if u know why is that happening, would be great to hear it from you ;)

Comment: My typo. When I changed the index, I forgot to change the line settings the float to $data['float' . $i] = $float[$i - 1]; (notice the minus 1).

Comment: Ok, you fully solved my problem. Thanks so much for your time ;)